# How to remove the memory leak issue because of the frameworks provided by the apple like AppKit , CoreAnimation

Tags: swift

We are seeing memory leaks observed in AppKit, Core Foundation classes and also some performance issues observed in nested table views.

Comment: What performance issues you facing, can you please describe here clearly ?

Comment: in my application when i navigate from my home screen to different tabs then again coming back to home screen ....in my cpu performance i find that it goes on increasing (means memory ) its not getting down ... and when i checked the memory leaks in instruments i find that there are leaks due to appkit,coreAnimation ets all the library files . i think because of these my app is taking more memory after launching and navigating to different tabs .